# Threejs - Reflectivitybitmap does not work on MeshLambertMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

**what works:**

I am using threejs revision 73.
I want to render a tool with the WebGLRenderer.
The tool consists of 3 Meshes. Each mesh consists of a BufferGeometry and a MeshLambertMaterial:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

The result looks like the following: [image: Tool without Bitmap]

**what I want to archive:**

Now I want to make the tool look more realistic by applying a Texture ("img/tablereflection.bmp", grayscale 256x256px, bmp). I am unsure what is the best approach if I want this texture to affect my reflectivity behavior.

What I do, is:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/tablereflection.bmp")
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

But the result looks like that:[image: Tool with Bitmap]

That is not what I want to have. It should look like:[image: ReferenceTool]

Can someone tell me please, what I might be missing?

***Edits***

My light function is

```
function initLight(scene, camera) {
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    var leftLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x888888, 0.7, 0);
    leftLight.position.set(-2, 5, 2);
    camera.add(leftLight);
    var rightLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x888888, 0.7, 0);
    rightLight.position.set(2, 5, 2);
    camera.add(rightLight);
}
```

I've already tried to use [The material browser for MeshLambertMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshLambertMaterial) and possibly was able to archieve what I wanted as you can see here [image: possibly correct result] using these settings [image: table inspector], but as you can see the Type is now empty and so I am not sure what happens behind the scene. Where is the error? Im glad for any hints.